# Not able to Autowire in CustomAuthenticationProvider in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to secure an application with spring security . Usually I would implement a custom UserDeatilsService and a CustomAuthenticationManager . But in this case as UserDetailsService only has one function                   `loadUserDeatils(String email)` . The problem is the class I have to use to retrieve the details of user does't have a function to load the details by only username . It need to have two parameters like username and password . So I went back to only implement a CustomAuthenticationManager and autowire the class there and get the details there itself and check it against the authentication ,but I am not being able to autowire it and it shows null . How can I achieve this or is there a better way to do this ??

MY Security Config :

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        /*@Autowired
        MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter; 
    @Autowired
    FilterChainProxy samlFilter; 
    @Autowired
    SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint;
    */

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    /* @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("metadataGeneratorFilter.toString() + samlEntryPoint.toString() + samlFilter.toString()+sdfsdf");
        auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user1")  
              .password("password1")
              .roles("user")
              .and()
            .withUser("admin") 
              .password("password")
              .roles("admin","user");
      }*/


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         try {
            http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/settings/api/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
             .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            // .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/index",true)       
             .and()
             .httpBasic();
        //   .defaultSuccessUrl("/", "true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("sadhiasdniaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider apiCustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }
    @Bean
    public SACSClientService sacsClientService(){
        return new SACSClientService();
    }
}
```

My CustomAuthenticationProvider :

```java
    @Component
    @Service
    public class ApiCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private SACSClientService  sacsClientService;
    @Autowired
    private ReferralDaoImpl referralDaoImpl;

    private ReferralProperty referralProperty =null ;
    /*@PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        ReferralProperty referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("sacs.service.base.url");           
      //  sacsClientService.setWebServiceBaseUrl("http://10.41.92.43:11140");
        sacsClientService.setWebServiceBaseUrl(referralProperty.getValue());
    }*/

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
       /* if(referralProperty==null)
        referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("sacs.service.base.url");            
      //  sacsClientService.setWebServiceBaseUrl("http://10.41.92.43:11140");

        sacsClientService.setWebServiceBaseUrl(referralProperty.getValue());
        if(sacsClientService == null )
            System.out.println("***** Response 12" +  "*****" );
        if(referralDaoImpl ==null)
            System.out.println("***** Response2134214234 " +  "*****" );*/

      //  GetUserDetailsRequest request  = new GetUserDetailsRequest(username, password);
        System.out.println(username + password + "sadfkjgas" + "user.getName() " );
     //   AuthenticateAndGetUserRequest sacsRequest = new AuthenticateAndGetUserRequest(username,password);
    //  AuthenticateAndGetUserResponse sacsResponse = sacsClientService.authenticateAndGetUser(sacsRequest);
        boolean loginStatus = false;
              GetUserDetailsResponse userDetailsResponse = sacsClientService.authenticateAndGetUser(request);
        UserSRO user = userDetailsResponse.getUser();*/

       /* if (user != null) {
            Set<AppRoleSRO> roles = user.getUserAppRoles();

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;
            if( roles !=null && !roles.isEmpty()) {
                authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                for (AppRoleSRO role : roles){
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAppRoleName()));
                }
            }
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password,authorities);
        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exist on SACS");
        }
    }*/


        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("aman", "12345",grantedAuths);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

SACSCliemtService is what I am having trouble autowiring . As soon as I use it it gives a error with one of the filters. The code works well when I comment out the SACSClient usage and pass dummy values

Comment: What error does it give ?

Comment: NullPointerException in UsernamePasswordFIlter

Comment: Evan : without stacktrace its impossible to see whats going wrong, please provide it.

Comment: I resolved it . thankyou . i was declaring the bean with a new method which isn't the right way to do . Thanks for your help